# Google Cloud IoT Python MQTT "out of memory" error

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, iot, paho

I'm seeing a hard to track down error with Google Cloud IoT. I have 2 projects set up with IoT API enabled. I'm using the same "quickstart" instructions to test, by setting up "my-registry" and "my-device". Let's call them projects A and B. I then run both the python and node examples pulled straight from git. The node example runs fine for both projects A and B, validated by pulling using gcloud. However, the python example works for project A, but with project b gets a "on disconnect. 1. out of memory" error. There is never a "connection accepted" message for B, but yes for A. "Out of memory" seems to be a generic error, not really the issue. It could represent a variety of issues in connectivity. Nothing on the server side Anyone encountered this one before? I appreciate any help in resolving or at least trace the eror.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's the python version. It was just about impossible to debug. I ended trying on many different devices/os to slowly isolate the issue. Looks like newly created projects rely on newer versions of google cloud sdk and python. Must have python 2.7.14.

Comment: Hi, I know this is old. But I am also running into the "Out of memory" error, but it cannot be the same reason as I am on python 3.7.3. Just wondering if you ever figured out another reason for this.

Comment: Sorry nothing more than what I found with the version. I would say in general, "Out of Memory" is indicative of another error. Make sure you have the latest Google Cloud IoT SDK, not just Python version.

Comment: I see. I will check it out as well. Thanks!